# NodeJS API creates two sessions because of "CORS preflight request"

Tags: node.js, vue.js, session, cors, passport.js

I am currently developing an API in NodeJS and a WebClient in VueJS.
I want to create a simple login/logout mechanism. The Webclient should send the request to the API and the API should handle the sessions of the different users and serving the data from its mongoDB.

Recently I came across a strange problem. When I want to login via WebClient, the browser shows me that it sends **two different headers** to the API. One "**OPTIONS**" header and one "**POST**" header. The POST header is sent due to my POST-Request (WebClient), which is clear. Due to [Mozillas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) explenation I also understand the OPTION header part since the browser wants to know if the API's CORS-configuration has been configured contrary for the WebClient or not (or something like this).

**But the problem now is the following:**

Due to the two different header-methods, **my API creates two session-IDs with just one login-post action (via WebClient)**, whereas one of these two sessions gets detached from the WebClient, unnecessarily consuming valuable space. This only happens through the WebClient. Using PostMan does not show this behaviour, only one session will be created since only one header is sent.

**What I want to know is:**

Since there is a reason for why the OPTIONS-header is sent, I want to know how I can prevent my API to create the second session via the WebClient.

Since this problem happened after testing my WebClient, it is clear to me that the WebClient is not configured or written properly, but I cannot tell **where** or **how** to prevent this since WebDev at this level is new to me. Like: Do I have to configure my WebClient or the API?

If more code is needed just tell me what you need and I will edit this post and attach the neede code.

**//////////////////// Code:**

**//// API:**

**// src/main.js:**

```js
const corsOptions = {
    origin: "http://localhost:8080",
    credentials:true,
    methods: "GET,HEAD,POST",
    preflightContinue: false,
    optionsSuccessStatus: 204
};
```

**// src/routes/LoginRoute.js:**

```js
router.post("/login", function(req,res,next){
  console.log("// Routes/Login");
  
  if(!req.user){
    console.log("---- Info: User is not logged in");
    
    passport.authenticate("local", (err, user, info) => {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }

      if (!user) {
        return res.status(401).json({success:false,errors:["User not found"]});
      }
      
      req.login(user, (err) => {
        if(err){
          return next(err);
        }
        console.log("---- Info: Routing success");
        return res.status(200).json({success:true});
      });

    })(req, res, next);
  }else{
    console.log("---- Info: User is already logged in");
    return res.status(403).json({success:false,errors:["Already logged in"]});
  }
});
```

**//// VueJS**

**// src/store/index.js**

```js
actions:{
    authenticate({commit},formData){
      console.log("---- Info: Vuex/Store/Action/Authenticate - Trying to log in");
      var url = "http://localhost:3000/api/login";
      console.log(formData);
      return Vue.axios.post(url,formData)
      .then((res)=>{
        console.log("---- Info: Vuex/Store/Action/Authenticate - Success");
        commit('login',res.data);
        return res.data;
      })
      .catch((err)=>{
        console.log("---- Error: Vuex/Store/Action/Authenticate");
        console.log(err);
        // commit('logout');
        return err;
      });
    }
}
```

**//////////////////// FireFox Network Analysis:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out what to do in order to prevent the browser to send two headers to the API server.

I had to configure the axios.post() overgive a header option to the funciton:

```js
const axiosHeaders = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }
};

Vue.axios.post(url,QueryString.stringify({username:username}),axiosHeaders)
.then(..)
[...]
```

Setting the **"Configure-Type"** as **"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"** will do the work, but the form-data has to be wrapped with the **QueryString.stringify(..)** function.

With this, the browser stops to send multiple headers with one post-request and in my case, it stops to create multiple sessions on my API.

I hope this will be usefull for anyone else too.

Answer (score 1):

I would believe that the cors package you apparently use would resolve this problem.

In any case this is not a problem with your frontend, it's handled by your backend and it's typical that the browser creates problems that aren't present with Postman. Postman is built to not care about browser CORS issues. You can however set a session in Postman for testing: https://blog.postman.com/sessions-faq/

Back to the problem: One approach is a middleware function for all or specific routes to filter out requests that already contain a session.

```js
    app.use((req, res, next) => {
      if (req.session) {
        // bypass new session creation, re-route or other solution
      }
      next()
    })
```

Another and more flexible approach is to target the OPTIONS header directly. I solved a similar problem in a serverless proxy function with a request handler that targets the OPTIONS header specifically.  It filters such requests out and returns an "OK signal" and generous headers to tell the browser it can go ahead with the real request, the POST.

You could try something like this as a general middleware or add it as a response to certain endpoints (code not tested, just freestyling the Express syntax here):

```js
    const optionsHeaders = {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type'
    }

    exports.reqHandler = async(req, res) => {
      if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        return {
          res.set(optionsHeaders)
          res.status(200)
        }
      }

     req.session.user = {}
     req.session.user.id =  uuid.v4()
     // etc. ...

      return res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        data: req.session.user
        msg: 'Session ID set'
      })

    }
```

Comment: I have a similar solution like your first example in my code where ich check für `req.user` (created through the PassportJS strategie). But even other variations do not seem to prevent my code to create a second session in the mongoDB...
For your second solution, i am still working on figuring out if i can handle this problem with optionHeaders.

Comment: Ok i have got it now! I had to configure my axios-post request on the front-end (WebClient aka VueJS). I just had to set the headers `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` in my `Vue.axios.post(url,QueryString.stringify(userInput),axiosHeaders);`. The Form-Data (userInput) had to be stringified for this to work.